# Как почитать и записать значение ячейки Excel Python

Tags: python, windows, excel, openpyxl

Как извлечь значение ячейки, например, которая не будет затронута при чтении на запас к примеру `zz 1`. Эта переменная отвечает за счетчик, т.е. когда последняя была запись на каком номере ячейки. Чтобы не использовать для этого .txt файл с числовым значением, а использовать Excel для этого.

Пример кода:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import requests
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook



directory_file = 'c:\\temp\\last_num.txt' 

with open(directory_file, 'r') as f:
    numer_last = int (f.readline())

print('numer_last: '+str(numer_last))



def get_img(url, size=(100, 100)):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if not r.ok:
        r.raise_for_error()
    r.raw.decode_content = True
    img = Image.open(r.raw)
    if size:
        img = img.resize(size)
    temp = BytesIO()
    img.save(temp, format="png")
    temp.seek(0)
    return Image.open(temp)


def insert_row(ws, img_url, name, num, size=(200,200)):
    img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(get_img(img_url, size=size))
    row_num = ws.max_row + 1
    cell_addr = f"A{row_num}"
    img.anchor = cell_addr
    ws.add_image(img)
    ws[f"B{row_num}"] = name
    ws[f"C{row_num}"] = num
    ws.row_dimensions[row_num].height = int(size[1] * .8)
    ws.column_dimensions["A"].width = int(size[0] * .2)

##############################################################################

size = (200, 200)
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active


#по одному


im_url_nastya = "https://s2.cdn.teleprogramma.pro/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/59d2d0c81e222b6a2dd496f448f454dd.jpg"
im_url_andrey = "https://ashevchenko.kiev.ua/assets/images/a-shevchenko-2.jpg"
im_url_yulya = "http://stuki-druki.com/aforizms/Yulia-Tymoshenko-01.jpg"


numer_last+=1
insert_row(ws, im_url_nastya, "Настя", numer_last, size=size)
numer_last+=1
insert_row(ws, im_url_andrey, "Андрей", numer_last, size=size)
numer_last+=1
insert_row(ws, im_url_yulya, "Юля", numer_last, size=size)





wb.save('c:/temp/test.xlsx')


with open(directory_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write("%s" % numer_last)

print('numer_last: '+str(numer_last))
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def get_last_id_from_excel(filename, sheetname="Sheet1", id_col="C"):
    wb = load_workbook(filename)
    ws = wb[sheetname]
    res = ws[f"C{ws.max_row}"].value
    wb.close()
    return res
```

использование:

```
In [19]: last_id = get_last_id_from_excel(r"C:\temp\test.xlsx", sheetname="Sheet", id_col="C")

In [20]: last_id
Out[20]: 3
```